# Difference between PM AM should be in 12 hour format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

Here is the code

```
    var d1 = new Date("01/01/2007 " + in_time);
    var d2 = new Date("01/01/2007 " + out_time);
    var timeDiff = (d2 - d1) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    timeDiff = Math.abs(timeDiff)
```

Exceptional cases 1:00 pm 12:00 am total hours 13 [I need total hours as to be 11 hours]

for example in_time is 8:00 pm and out_time is 12:00 am

Exceptional cases 2:00 pm 12:00 am total hours 14 [I need total hours as to be 10 hours]

Exceptional cases 3:00 pm 12:00 am total hours 15 [I need total hours as to be 9 hours]

Difference between AM and PM are right but PM AM calculation is in 24 hour format i want it as a 12 hour format.

Comment: what is `in_time` and `out_time`?

Comment: how can the difference be in hour format? difference in time is not same as time itself.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: set var d2 as next date not the same as the d1.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the bug:

```
var d1 = new Date("01/01/2007 " + in_time);
var d2 = new Date("01/01/2007 " + out_time);
                        ^
                        |
                       BUG
```

Since you're assuming the date to be the same, it means that 12am will ALWAYS be before whatever time you calculate with. So the calculation is correct. To fix this you only need to remember that 12am means the first second of the first hour of the next day.

Comment: Then for getting the desired result what should i need to change?

Comment: @DON: For 12am you should change the date to be the next day. I didn't write example code because I wasn't sure what that should be. Where I'm from that should be "02/01/2007" which is 2nd January but I'm afraid javascript may interpret that to mean 1st February.

Comment: @DON: Even worse, it could be 2nd Jan or 1st Feb depending on locale.